# TS2307: Cannot find module 'passport'

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

Using VS 2017, I started a new project using the TypeScript `Basic Node.js Express 4 Application` template.

I then used npm to install `passport`. `passport` is shown under the npm node in Solution Explorer and there are also passport folders in node_modules. Next I added (imitating the `import express = require('express')` in one of the template files):

```
import passport = require("passport");
```

But that resulted in:

> TS2307 Cannot find module 'passport'

What am I missing that could make this work?

I have been searching but cannot find much documentation about using TypeScript, especially with Node, in Visual Studio.

Comment: Most likely, you've not installed the typings: `npm install @types/passport --save`

Comment: Does the `@` and `/` have special meaning? I tried using the npm tool in Visual Studio, but got "No results found" if I typed in @types/passport. So I did it on the command line in the Package Manager Console, but no entry is added to package.json. It compiled and ran once successfully. When I tried to compile again, tons of errors were produced.

Comment: Yep, the `@` refers to a [scoped package](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope). See [`@types`](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/@types.html) in [basarat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390330/basarat)'s book.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `declare module "passport"`

## More

Covered with other tips in the JS migration guide : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/migrating.html

Comment: What does `declare module "passport"` do?  Where can find more information about the `declare` word? Is it a command, a directive, a keyword, a function?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue. I just resaved the file, and everything is fine.